# Fully automated sending and replying from Excel, through Outlook

Tags: excel, email, outlook

Greettings. This is my first post here, so bear with me.

I planned to design a database software, for the time being, in MS Access. One of the functions I plan for this software is the submitting of documents for approval. The ideia is to, from the database (report or form), click to send a pre-written e-mail, with a document in attachment, but, that pre-written e-mail would have a link to send back an also pre-written e-mail, for a quick sort of automated response/reply, but without using reply from Outlook. The objective is people to send from DB, other receive, read document, and if approved, click to "auto respond", and Outlook would be just a "reading" software with all the sending done in the background.

Although I plan on an Access app, I drafted an example in Excel, for more rapid testing (the target prop is used to pass strings where ever it can hold a string). Here is the code so far.

```
Private Function SendEmailWithOutlook(MessageTo As String, Subject As String, MessageBody As String, myAttachment As String)

' Define app variable and get Outlook using the "New" keyword
Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem  ' An Outlook Mail item

' Create a new email object
Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

' Add the To/Subject/Body to the message and display the message
With olMailItem
    .to = MessageTo
    .Subject = Subject
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = MessageBody
    .Attachments.Add (myAttachment)
    .Send       ' Send the message immediately
End With

' Release all object variables
Set olMailItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Function
```

(From MS site)

Function to prepare and send code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim myMsg As String

If Target.TextToDisplay = "ASK APROVAL" Then

Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E:E").Find(Target.ScreenTip, LookIn:=xlValues)

If c Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "File Not Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Retrieves the file name, stored in a cell to the right of the path
myFile = c.Offset(0, 1).Value

'Prepares the file for HTML reading
myFile = Replace(myFile, " ", "%20")

myMsg = "<HTML><BODY><SCRIPT type=""VBScript"">" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "FUNCTION SendEmail()" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "With olMailItem" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & ".to = ""firstsender@company.com""" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & ".Subject = ""Approval""" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & ".BodyFormat = olFormatHTML" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & ".HTMLBody = ""<HTML><BODY>The document metioned bellow is approved!<P>"
myMsg = myMsg & myFile
myMsg = myMsg & "<P>(Auto Response)</BODY></HTML>""" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & ".Send" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "End With" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "Set olMailItem = Nothing" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "Set olApp = Nothing" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "End Function" & Chr(13)
myMsg = myMsg & "</SCRIPT>Dear Boss<P>Attached to this e-mail is a document for your approval. Thanks.<P><BR><a href=""#"" onclick=""SendMail()"">Click for auto response.</a>"
myMsg = myMsg & "</BODY></HTML>"

SendEmailWithOutlook "approver@company.com", "Approval of Document in Attachment", myMsg, Target.ScreenTip

Set c = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

The e-mail is sent with sucess, but the link for the return e-mail, although present, doesn't do anything on click. That's the problem.

From testing, by debug in the immediate window, the full HTML code that's sent apears correct, with every quote on place.

As other options of code, i have previously tryed with a simple javascript function, with "windows.location.href:'mailto:...", but had no effect. The first thing i tryed was sending through HTMLbody a FORM, but the submit button apeared as text in brackets.

I don't know if this is possible or not, or if my line of thinking is off. So, appreciate some help. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts will not work in email bodies for security reasons. Also the link in the email body is not a good idea, it will not work the way you want. Instead, you may consider developing an add-in which can be installed on remote machines. When you get such an email (where you need to get any feedback) you can add a ribbon button to the Outlook UI, for example, an *agree and reply* button in addition to the standard buttons. In the button's event handler you may add a user property which you can get on your Inbox. Does it make sense?

Comment: Operationally speaking, it does. I'm trying to build a system, of which I'm NOT the IT admin, adding the fact that people have some resistence to new tools. It's an application to use in a company/factory. The master ideia as a final app, is that people use just the software in Access, for everything (even nesting the outlook inside Access through API). But that, I can't do right now, and I planned to extend this function to other applications. Like this, a ribbon might not work (or might work). But thanks for the idea. Might come in handy.